# Using PhangomJS in Docker Alpine

Tags: jenkins, phantomjs, alpine

I am trying to use Jenkins as a docker container. For this purpose, I use the [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/). As we have some integrations tests based on Selenium (Vaadin Workbench really), I need to run phantomjs as headless. The tests are executed correctly the same as before being dockerized. My web application (a server) executes correctly and phantomjs is launched later as a client and executes all tests correctly. This is the expected behaviour.

Now I like the idea of using jenkins in an **alpine** system. In general I use alpine in my other docker containers due to its small size. Jenkins docker official image also has an alpine based image that I can use it. In general I have no problem with other tools I need to install (ansible, ...). And they works great in the alpine version. But I am facing an issue with phantomjs.

First of all, I install phantomjs from a github project that has an alpine compilation. Here there are the commands I use:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add fontconfig && \
mkdir -p /usr/share && \
curl -L https://github.com/Overbryd/docker-phantomjs-alpine/releases/download/2.11/phantomjs-alpine-x86_64.tar.bz2 | tar xj --directory /usr/share && \
chmod +x /usr/share/phantomjs/phantomjs && \
ln -s /usr/share/phantomjs/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

It seems that works fine. If I access to the docker container with a `docker exec -it jenkins sh`, I can execute phantomjs from the command line. But when jenkins executes the tests, I have this error:

```
WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start
```

Before any test starts. The application server is running (I can connect to it from my browser) but jenkins cannot launch phantomjs to connect it. I have checked the [phantomjs logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161596/selemium-and-phantomjs-timed-out-waiting-for-driver-server-to-start) to see if this is the issue but it has permissions to write (still, the file is empty). Still I can execute phantomjs from the command line, but jenkins + selenium cannot.

Of course, run jenkins in an alpine machine is not mandatory and now I go back to the standard docker image based in openjdk. But now I am curious about this issue and I am not sure if this is a phantomjs issue or an alpine issue. Or maybe I need some extra configuration or packets to run phantomjs in alpine.

Do anybody has the same issue when using jenkins + alpine + selenium (or equivalent)? Any clue of what can cause this error?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and have not found a solution, though in my case it's just alpine+selenium(selenide)/